# Adding formula for drop down list in Excel VBA issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code that will create a drop down list when i double click a cell, but i want to change the formula for the drop down list so i can make dependent drop down lists. The problem is that the qoutes i use in the formula interfere with the ones delimiting the formula itself. I've put part of the code where the problem is down. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
With Range("H" & myRow & ":H" & myRow).Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=OFFSET(INDIRECT($G13),0,0,COUNTA(INDIRECT($G13&"Col")),1)"
```

Thank you

Comment: Just double the ones inside the formula string - `""Col""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes for literal expression...

```
With Range("H" & myRow & ":H" & myRow).Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=OFFSET(INDIRECT($G13),0,0,COUNTA(INDIRECT($G13&""Col"")),1)"
```